# actionbutton saving text shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple sampling code and I'd like to print the past results (in the current session) in a table below. However, I'm having difficulty figuring it out. Any ideas?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Randomization"),
  sidebarPanel(p("Click the button to randomize a class"),
    br(),
    actionButton("randomize", "Randomize")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("vText")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  video <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
  output$vText <-  renderText({
    if (input$randomize == 0) {
      return()
  }  else {
    paste(input$randomize, ".", replicate(1, sample(video, 1, replace =   TRUE)))
  }  
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For example (using the code above), if I pressed the actionButton 3 times, then below the main text box would say "3. v1" and below that it would have the past sampling (eg. "1. v1, 2. v3")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the current text in a session variable. Note the `<<-` which following a fortune cookie is allowed only for people who would never use it, but here it is protected against misuse by the `txt <- ""` in the session.
The trickiest part is the carriage-return; maybe someone finds a more elegant method to avoid the double `paste`.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  video <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
  txt <- ""
  output$vText <-  renderText({
    if (input$randomize == 0) {
      return()
    }  else {
      txt <<- paste0(paste(txt,
            input$randomize, ".", replicate(1, sample(video, 1, replace =   TRUE))),sep = "\n")
      txt
    }
  })
})
```